# Filament Form: Required Validation Not Triggering for Textarea Inside a Tab

Tags: laravel-filament

I have a form with the following structure, where I've set required() on Textarea::make('content') inside a tab. However, during registration, the required validation check does not trigger.

```
    public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('author_name')
                    ->label('作成者')
                    ->columnSpan('full')
                    ->default(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user()->name)
                    ->readOnly(),
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('title')
                    ->label('件名')
                    ->required()
                    ->columnSpan('full'),
                Forms\Components\Tabs::make('Label')
                    ->tabs([
                        Forms\Components\Tabs\Tab::make('html')
                            ->schema([
                                Forms\Components\Textarea::make('content')
                                    ->rules([
                                        function () {
                                            return function (string $attribute, $value, \Closure $fail) {
                                                if ($value === '') {
                                                    $fail('The :attribute is invalid.');
                                                }
                                            };
                                        },
                                    ])
                                    ->required()
                                    ->label('本文')
                                    ->columnSpan('full')
                                    ->rows(10),
                            ]),
                        Forms\Components\Tabs\Tab::make('preview')
                            ->schema([
                                \App\Forms\Components\HtmlPreview::make('content')
                                    ->label('プレビュー')
                                    ->columnSpan('full'),
                            ]),
                    ])
                    ->columnSpan('full'),
                Forms\Components\DateTimePicker::make('sent_at')
                    ->label('配信日時')
                    ->minDate(now()),
            ]);
    }
```

If anyone has a solution, please let me know.

Thank you in advance.

I tried the following code to implement validation in a Filament form, specifically to ensure that the content field within a tab is required. However, the custom validation rule I defined does not seem to trigger.

```
    Forms\Components\Tabs::make('Label')
        ->tabs([
            Forms\Components\Tabs\Tab::make('html')
                ->schema([
                    Forms\Components\Textarea::make('content')
                        ->rules([
                            function () {
                                return function (string $attribute, $value, \Closure $fail) {
                                    if ($value === '') {
                                        $fail('The :attribute is invalid.');
                                    }
                                };
                            },
                        ])
                        ->required()
                        ->label('本文')
                        ->columnSpan('full')
                        ->rows(10),
                ]),
        ]);
```

I expected that this setup would enforce a validation check when the form is submitted, specifically checking if the content textarea is empty. If empty, it should display an error message stating 'The content is invalid.' However, when I submit the form with the content field empty, no validation error appears, and the form submission proceeds as if the field were not required.